# fill a DataSet in Visual Studio 2015 Express (Windows Forms Application)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, dataset, windows-forms-designer, create-table

i want to know if there is an easy way to do this. I have created a simple Windows Form Application with a DataSet and created a table (Games) inside with a few columns (ID,Title,Description,Developer,Year).

Then i created a ListBox object with reference to this DataSet and selected a column to show (Games.Title). Then there are a few Labels next to the ListBox to show the values of the other columns.

Now i want to know if i can fill the DataSet inside Visual Studio without much coding - like if you edit an Access Database in MS Access...

Currently i fill the DataSet with the following code at the start of the application:

```
DataRow CrNewLine = dataSet1.Tables["Games"].NewRow();
CrNewLine["Title"] = "The Title of the Game";
CrNewLine["Description"] = "This is the Description. Farewell.";
CrNewLine["Developer"] = "Warner Interactive Entertainment Ltd.";
CrNewLine["Year"] = "1996";
dataSet1.Tables["Games"].Rows.Add(CrNewLine);
```

But this is very code intense if i want to Add 200 rows in this table...
And i don't want to use an external source like SQL Database or Access Database.
The Data, Code and Application should be all in one EXE after compiling.

So is the an easier way to fill a DataSet Table with values?

Thanks for any answer!

Comment: You can use [Rows.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/adding-data-to-a-datatable) to add the values for a row in one statement, but even with 200 rows this is an onerous task. If you don't want a database you could use a simple text file.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to store the file as a `JSON` text file embed it into your application as an `Embedded Resource`.

Using a sample Json file such as below:

```
{
    "Data": [
        {
            "Title": "Title 1",
            "Description": "Description 1",
            "Developer": "Developer 1",
            "Year": 1996
        },
        {
            "Title": "Title 2",
            "Description": "Description 2",
            "Developer": "Developer 2",
            "Year": 1997
        },

        {
            "Title": "Title 3",
            "Description": "Description 3",
            "Developer": "Developer 3",
            "Year": 1998
        }
    ]
}
```

Next you can embed this into your solution by changing the build action (in the properties pane) to `Embedded Resource` this will embed you JSON data file into your assembly output.
[image: Embedded Resource Build Action]

Next we can use [`JSON.Net`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to deserialize the data into a `Dataset`.

```
public static DataSet LoadData()
{
    var asm = typeof(Program).Assembly;
    var jsonText = "";
    using(var stream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream($"{asm.GetName().Name}.data.json"))
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            jsonText = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
    DataSet dataSet = null;
    try
    {
        dataSet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(jsonText);
    }
    catch
    {
    }
    return dataSet;
}
```

The method above is pretty straight forward. First we read the JSON data (file name is `data.json`) from the assembly. Note the path to the file should be `YourNameSpace.<FileName>`

Next we use the [`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeDataSet.htm) to return convert the JSON text to a `Dataset` object. The result will contain a single table named `Data` (the root node of our JSON file) that you can then use in your application.

Now you just need to add to the JSON file to add more data. Now as you want to include this file into your assembly (exe) and not have an addition file you wont be able to write data to it (as its embedded in the application).

However if you need write access you could (on launch) detect if the file exists in the application path. If it doesn't exist, you can read the default data file and then write the contents to an output file such as below.

```
public static DataSet LoadDataSet()
{
    var asm = typeof(Program).Assembly;

    string filePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(asm.CodeBase).ToLowerInvariant().Replace(@"file:\", "");
    filePath = Path.Combine(filePath, "data.json");
    string jsonText = null;
    if (!File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        using (var stream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream($"{asm.GetName().Name}.data.json"))
        {
            using (var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {
                stream.CopyTo(fs);
            }
        }
    }
    else
        jsonText = File.ReadAllText(filePath);

    DataSet dataSet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(jsonText);
    return dataSet;
}

public static void SaveDataSet(DataSet dataSet)
{
    var asm = typeof(Program).Assembly;
    string filePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(asm.CodeBase).ToLowerInvariant().Replace(@"file:\", "");
    filePath = Path.Combine(filePath, "data.json");

    string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataSet, Formatting.Indented);
    File.WriteAllText(filePath, jsonText);
}
```

In the example code above we are loading the `Dataset` by first checking to see if the file exists in the current application directory. If it does not exist we are effecivly copying the contents from the Embedded Resource to disk using a `FileStream`.

Then we are able to just call `File.ReadAllText()` to read the contents from disk and then convert it to a dataset using the method previous.

We then have a method to save the changes to the dataset. Now as the resource is embedded into the application we cannot modify the version in the assembly, however we can just overwrite the file on the disk.

Answer (score 0):

You can put all the data in an xml file and call dataSet.ReadXml()

If you want some help with the schema, put a few rows of data into your dataSet and dataSet.writeXml(), then pop it open in a text editor and get an idea for how it needs to be structured and extended..